# Using Array Variables For FILE_GET_CONTENTS

Tags: php, arrays

I have a script all done now and everything has been debugged and it works, except for the last hurdle. This script grabs pertinent information on bank web sites, takes that data and uses it to populate a template and then it's all posted to Wordpress - BUT I get an error because the file_get_contents function fails taking each url from the Array.

I've var_dumped the array and all the URLS are there in the [0] key, so this is what I tried.

- master data is the scraped URL source the script uses
- urlscrape_array is the collection of URLS

  $master_data = file_get_contents($urlscrape_array[0]);

When I run the script using a URL like below it works beautifully every time;

```
   $master_data = file_get_contents("http://www.somesite/somepage.html");
```

This is the error I get when I try to use the first example'

```
   Warning: file_get_contents() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given    in /home3/path/public_html/mysite.com/boise_project/scriptmainpage.php on line 13
```

As requested here is a sample of the var_dump on $urlscrape_array[0]

```
  array(504) { [0]=> string(56) "http://www.somepage.com/somepage-3178.html" [1]=> string(54) "http://www.somepage.com/somepage-16.html" [2]=> string(56) "http://www.somepage.com/somepage-3202.html" [3]=> string(56) "http://www.somepage.com/somepage-4324.html" [4]=> string(56) "http://www.somepage.com/somepage-4777.html" [5]=> string(56) "http://www.somepage.com/somepage-5140.html" [6]=> string(56) "http://www.somepage.com/somepage-5220.html" [7]=> string(56) "http://www.somepage.com/somepage-9205.html" [8]=> string(56) "http://www.somepage.com/somepage-3251.html" [9]=> string(56) "http://www.somepage.com/somepage-3323.html" [10]=> string(56) "http://www.somepage.com/some-page-3797.html" [11]=> string(56) "http://www.somepage.com/some-page-4145.html" [12]=> string(56) "http://www.somepage.com/some-page-3191.html" [13]=> string(55) "http://www.somepage.com/some-page-329.html" [14]=> string(56) etc....


   Error as per the foreach statement provided by Uptown
   Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home3/bettyt45/public_html/bdbud.com/boise_project/boise-wordpress.php on line 12
```

NULL

print_r resulst below;

```
    Array ( [0] => Array ( [0] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-3178.html [1] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-16.html [2] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-3202.html [3] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-4324.html [4] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-4777.html [5] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-5140.html [6] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-5220.html [7] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-9205.html [8] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-3251.html [9] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-3323.html [10] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-3797.html [11] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-4145.html [12] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-3191.html [13] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-329.html [14] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-3341.html [15] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-3758.html [16] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-4180.html [17] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-9014.html [18] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-5987.html [19] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-1542.html [20] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-3004.html [21] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-9034.html [22] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-3385.html [23] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-3435.html [24] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-6389.html [25] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-6992.html [26] => http://www.somesite.com/some-page-7051.html
```

HERE IS THE CODE I USED TO CREATE THE ARRAY ABOVE;

```
       $urlscrape_data = file_get_contents('http://www.mysite.com/boise_project/boise-urls.htm');
       preg_match_all('~http\:\/\/www.somesite.com\/some\-page\-\d{1,4}?\.html~',   $urlscrape_data, $urlscrape_matches);
```

$urlscrape_array = $urlscrape_matches;

Comment: I suspect that there is something else going on that is now shown your in example. The file_get_contents() is pretty straight forward and your example looks correct. Is this is a while loop by any chance? Can you show more?

Comment: Also can you do a var_dump or print_r on the $urlscrape_array[0] var and show us the output?

Comment: There is no for_each loop or while loop - I thought that every time the script loaded with a cronjob it would process another file and quit. All scheduled with a cron job. Or do I HAVE to have a for_each or while statement to pull the URLs from the Array?? Thanks for your considerate help uptownhr.

Comment: If you have an array, a `foreach` is considered the best way to iterate through that array. You don't HAVE to do it that way, it it's the cleanest and simplest way to do it.

Comment: if that is the vardump of $urlscrape_array[0], then you need to use, $urlscrape_array[0][0]. $urlscrape_array[0] contains an array.

Comment: Thanks @Machavity - in this case I don't need to load many pages per day - like 20-30, so I was hoping a cron job in the middle of the night would not bother outside servers. Everytime I load the script page it runs a file and does a post as long as the file_get_contents is working with a URL and not the array variable.

Comment: HEY @uptownhr! When I load the script it now grabs the first URL and processes it - thanks. However on the second load it runs again and processes the same URL.

Comment: are you using the foreach statement i wrote in my answer?

Comment: Oh yes - thanks - I've tried both #uptownhr

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach($urlscrape as $url){
 echo $url; //confirm url is changing
 $master_data = file_get_contents($url);
 echo $master_data;
}
```

Comment: Thanks - got the error I added above. I tried [0][0] also and same error.

Comment: Ok, I probably made a mistake. Try the updated loop now. Should display the url being fetched with file_get_contents.

Comment: Wait a minute - there is no var $urlscrape -it's $urlscrape_array - I'll try that

Comment: var results on $urlscrape_array show as I posted above with all the links - still fails with a blank post going to WP - still something with getting the data successfully pulled from the the array to $master data - never been here before so THANK YOU VERY much for your efforts here

Comment: Is the foreachloop posting the urls as expected right now? Are the $Urls being echoed as expected?

Comment: No - still the invalid foreach statement - the echo works but as a runaway - needs a break or whatever stops it. My guess now is the foreach has to be using the => in it to pick up the array keys

Comment: something like this? from the php site? foreach($arr as $key=>$value) 
 { 
     unset($arr[$key + 1]); 
     echo $value . PHP_EOL; 
 }

Comment: The key actually isn't needed. the problem right now is the foreach is not running because the $urlscrape_array is not an array; according to the error. can you do a print_r($urlscrape_array) instead and post the result?

Comment: It's up - think you are on to something - might have to change the code use to create the array